# Unramified extensions of a given degree

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, ramification

Let $K \neq \mathbb{Q} $ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. For a given integer $n$, how to construct an unramified extension of $K$ of degree $n$ ?

EDIT: If not then under what conditions on $K$, the above construction is possible ?

Comment: Adjoin a suitable root of unity.

Comment: the $n$th cyclotomic field over $\mathbb{Q}$ is ramified at all primes dividing $n$.

Comment: If $K$ is a local field, then there exists a unique unramified extension of each degree. See Serre's book on local fields.

Comment: See some previous MO questions: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26491/is-there-a-ring-of-integers-except-for-z-such-that-every-extension-of-it-is-ram/26526#26526 and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/41219/number-fields-with-no-unramified-extensions. The first link shows $\mathbf Q(i)$ has no everywhere unramified extensions of degree greater than $1$, abelian or otherwise. So in that sense it is just like $\mathbf Q$.