# Number fields with finite maximal unramified $p$-extensions

Tags: nt.number-theory, ramification

As discussed in the question [number fields with no unramified extensions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41219/number-fields-with-no-unramified-extensions), it is an open question that whether there are an infinite number of number fields that have no unramified extensions. Inspired by this, I would like to ask the weaker question as follows：

**Question:**

1. Let $p$ be a fixed prime. Are there infinitely many number fields such that its maximal unramified $p$-extension is finite?
2. Is there a prime $p$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^m})$ admits a finite maximal unramified $p$-extension for all positive integer $m$?

---

**Update:** the answer for question $1$ is Yes. In Theorem I of [Construction of maximal unramified p-extensions with prescribed Galois groups by Manabu Ozaki](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00222-010-0289-0), it's proved that

> for any prime $p$ and any given finite $p$-group $G$, there exists a number field $F$ such that the Galois group of the maximal unramified $p$-extension over $F$ is isomorphic to $G$.

Since there are infinitely many finite $p$-groups, we see that there are infinitely many number fields such that its maximal unramified $p$-extension is finite.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to question 2 is also yes. To see this, we need the following two facts.

**Fact 1:** Let $\zeta_{p^{m}}$ be a primitive $p^m$-th root of unity. Then the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^{m}})$ divisible by $p$ iff the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ is. See Example 12.4 on p.136 of [Koch, H., 2002. Galois theory of p-extensions. Springer Science & Business Media.]

**Fact 2:** A number field K can be imbeded into another number field with class number prime to $p$ iff the degree of the maximal unramified p-extension (or p-class field tower) of $K$ is finite. See Proposition 2 on p.232 of [Cassels, J.W.S. and Fröhlich, A., Algebraic number theory, London, 1986.]

By Fact 1 and 2, those primes $p$ satisfying question 2 are exactly those primes such that the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ is prime to $p$, i.e. they are exactly [regular primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_prime).

Comment: It is expected, but not yet known, that there are infinitely many regular primes.  Infinitude of the set of irregular primes is known.