# The Shafarevich Conjecture and motivic Langlands stacks.

Tags: nt.number-theory, langlands-conjectures, motives

Hi, I recently learned about an amazing conjecture of Shafarevich
(proved by Faltings) about the finiteness of the number
of curves of a fixed genus with good reduction outside a
finite number of primes. Moreover, there are no curves
of genus $> 0$ at all with good reduction everywhere (Abrashkin/Fontaine).

Is there an analog of this theorem for
stacks (of the type described below), and how does this connect
to the Langlands program?

From what I understand, the moduli space
$\mathcal{M}_{1,1}$ of elliptic curves
can be thought of a stack with good reduction everywhere
over $\mathbb{Z}$. (Mumford computed that the
Picard group of this stack is $\mathbf{Z}/12\mathbf{Z}$.)
 Moreover, the generic
fiber of this stack of the form
$[X/G]$, where $X/\mathbf{Q}$
 is a smooth proper curve and $G$ is a finite group.
I want to restrict attention to exactly this special class of stacks (do they have a name?).

First question: can one classify smooth proper stacks $\mathcal{X}$
over $\mathbf{Z}$ with generic fiber $[X/G]$ for some smooth
proper curve $X$ over $\mathbf{Q}$ and finite group $G$? Are there finitely
many such stacks?
Is $\mathcal{M}_{1,1}$ the only one with negative euler characteristic?

Second question: are there finitely many smooth stacks
$\mathcal{X}$ over $\mathbf{Z}[1/N]$ where $N$ and
$\chi(\mathcal{X})$ are fixed?

Finally, is there any Tannakian/Langlands/Motivic formulism
that attaches some motivic type object to $\mathcal{M}_{1,1}$
that isn't just the "trivial" motive attached to $\mathbf{P}^1$?

Apologies for any vagueness in this question, hopefully a
more seasoned MO Langlands pro like David Hansen or James Taylor can help me out.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31538/non-abelian-class-field-theory-and-fundamental-groups/33425#33425

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10860/why-no-abelian-varieties-over-z/29937#29937

Comment: Dear Professor Dalawat - thanks for the links! This is addressing the last question I presume? If I understand you, you are saying that the "1-motive" should be an abelian variety over $\mathbf{Z}$ which can't exist.
But I was thinking along the following lines: is there some integral "Motivic like" object $[\mathcal{M}]$ for which 
"$H^1$" returned $\mathbf{Z}/\mathbf{Z}12$. I don't even know if Motives are supposed to form a category with "integral" properties... and maybe this is related to "torsion" automorphic forms...
perhaps your remarks merely expose my ignorance, but I like to dream!

Comment: I provided the links merely because they discuss the relationship of the Langlands' Programme with Fontaine-Abrashkin. 

Comment: (If the "Worst notation ever" question was still open, I would add the notation " $X/k$ " often used by algebraic geometers to mean "the scheme $X$ is defined over 
$k$"!) 

Comment: I don't see why you would expect the pullback of motives attached to a coarse moduli map to be an isomorphism.  Integrality is inherent in basically all modern treatments (see Levine's book, Voevodsky's papers, etc.).  Also, it is not too difficult to make twisted genus zero curves with negative Euler characteristic and "good reduction" everywhere.

Comment: Dear Professor Carnahan, I would love it if you could explain the construction ("it is not too difficult to make genus zero curves with .. good reudction everywhere").

Comment: Naturally $X/k$ is the notation, I say to old Qfwfq, what else could it have been?

Comment: One minor detail: $\mathcal{M}_{1,1}$ is not proper, and it is really easy to construct hyperbolic curves that aren't proper, even without using stacks.  The Deligne-Mumford compactification has Picard group $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$.